Jenkins - prevent repo checkout on some nodes or stages?
By default, a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job will download the entire Git repository to each build node that is used for a build stage.
If some build stages don't need the files from the repository (for example, a machine which only signs files generated by other build nodes), this fills the disk with files that never get used.
Is there any way to prevent Jenkins from downloading the repo on a certain build stage or on a certain build node?
